# how to apply iddata into calculation?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to figure out how to combine the input and output data into the ARX model and then apply it into the BIC (Bayesian Information Criterion) formula. Below is the code that I am currently working on:

```
for i=1:30; %% Set Model Order
    data=iddata(output,input,1);
    model = arx(data,[8 9 i]);
    yp = predict(model,data);
    ye = regress(data,yp{1,1}(1:4018,1));
    M(i) = var(yp);
    BIC(i)=(N+i*(log(N)-1))/(N-i)*log(M(i));
end
```

But it does not work. It keeps on giving me an error that's something like below:

"The syntax "Data{...}" is not supported. Use the "getexp" command to
extract individual experiments from an IDDATA object."
I did not understand what does that mean. Can someone explain it to me and where do I do wrong on my piece of code?

Update:
I tried to do it something like below, so far, there is no error. But then the graph for this BIC will be always straight line. Is something wrong with my regression part? how should I do for the regression?

```
N=length(rainfall_model);
for i=1:20; % Set Model Order
    data=iddata(rainfall_model,tmax_model,1);
    %d1 = getexp(data,1);
    model = arx(data,[50 9 i]);
    yp=predict(model,data);
    y = yp.y ;
    d1 = data.y ;
    ye = (d1).^2 - (y).^2;
    M(i)= mse(ye);
    BIC(i)=(N+i*(log(N)-1))/(N-i)*log(M(i));
end
```

Comment: The variable 'i' in "model = arx(data,[50 9 i]);" does not set the model order. It sets the number of delays in the model. What kind of model are you trying to fit your data? You should check "help arx" in the toolbox documentation.

Comment: yes I am trying to fit arx model. and yes "i" is for the delay. Sorry for the confusion. The comment was not meant to be there. I am just trying to find the lowest values for the delay from 1-20 range.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, yp returned from the 'predict' command is an iddata object and the cell notation '{...}' cannot be used with it. If you want to do regression, you have to extract the input (yp.u) or the output (yp.y) data from it.

Also, the command 'regress' does not work with idddata objects, since it is not a system identification toolbox function. Again you have to extract input or output data from the 'data' and 'yp' variables before calling it.

Update: To see what's in the iddata objects (data and yp), do

```
get(data)
get(yp)
```

You would see that you can extract the output data in two equivalent ways:

```
yp.y
yp.OutputData
```

Similarly, for the input data.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I am new to this system identification toolbox. Can you explain to me how do I extract the input or the output? I have tried using the "getexp" command, but I am not sure on how to use this command. And what if I am using SISO data (single input and single output), does not mean that we have to use both input and output data? Thanks in advance